# How to get all public (both get and set) string properties of a type

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to make a method that will go through a list of generic objects and replace all their properties of type `string` which is either `null` or empty with a replacement.

How is a good way to do this?

I have this kind of... shell... so far:

```
public static void ReplaceEmptyStrings<T>(List<T> list, string replacement)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties( -- What BindingFlags? -- );

    foreach(var p in properties)
    {
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) p.GetValue(item, null)))
                p.SetValue(item, replacement, null);
        }
    }
}
```

So, how do I find all the properties of a type that are:

- Of type `string`
- Has public `get`
- Has public `set`

  ?

---

I made this test class:

```
class TestSubject
{
    public string Public;
    private string Private;

    public string PublicPublic { get; set; }
    public string PublicPrivate { get; private set; }
    public string PrivatePublic { private get; set; }
    private string PrivatePrivate { get; set; }
}
```

The following does not work:

```
var properties = typeof(TestSubject)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(ø => ø.CanRead && ø.CanWrite)
        .Where(ø => ø.PropertyType == typeof(string));
```

If I print out the Name of those properties I get there, I get:

> PublicPublic
> PublicPrivate
> PrivatePublic

In other words, I get two properties too much.

---

***Note**: This could probably be done in a better way... using nested foreach and reflection and all here... but if you have any great alternative ideas, please let me know cause I want to learn!*

Comment: I'm so in love with using `ø` as the variable. Will adopt this to all of my LINQ code from now on. Looks so elegant. 

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Your code rewritten.  Does not use LINQ nor var.

```
public static void ReplaceEmptyStrings<T>(List<T> list, string replacement)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {
        // Only work with strings
        if (p.PropertyType != typeof(string)) { continue; }

        // If not writable then cannot null it; if not readable then cannot check it's value
        if (!p.CanWrite || !p.CanRead) { continue; }

        MethodInfo mget = p.GetGetMethod(false);
        MethodInfo mset = p.GetSetMethod(false);

        // Get and set methods have to be public
        if (mget == null) { continue; }
        if (mset == null) { continue; }

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)p.GetValue(item, null)))
            {
                p.SetValue(item, replacement, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example will first of all replace *all* values, and second of all, the CanWrite property doesn't seem to work the way we would think it would... =/

Comment: The CanWrite indeed does work the way it should.  Can you explain what makes you think to the contrary?

Comment: As my example shows, a public property that is declared as i.e. public string Something {get; private set;}, will return true for both CanRead and CanWrite, even though I shouldn't be able to write, since the setter is private.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean.  The CanWrite and CanRead are just checking if a set and get accessor are assigned to the property.  Check the public-ness of the get and set methods to determine if you can call them.  I have updated my code.

Comment: Aaah, there we go! Thank you =)

Answer (score 16):

You will find the properties as such with `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`. Then you will need to examine each PropertyInfo instance by checking the CanWrite and CanRead properties, in order to find out whether they are are readable and/or writeable.

Update: code example

```
PropertyInfo[] props = yourClassInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
{
    if (props[i].PropertyType == typeof(string) && props[i].CanWrite)
    {
        // do your update
    }
}
```

---

I looked into it more in detail after your update. If you also examine the MethodInfo objects returned by GetGetMethod and GetSetMethod you will hit the target, I think;

```
 var properties = typeof(TestSubject).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(ø => ø.CanRead && ø.CanWrite)
        .Where(ø => ø.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Where(ø => ø.GetGetMethod(true).IsPublic)
        .Where(ø => ø.GetSetMethod(true).IsPublic);
```

By default these two methods return only public getters and setters (risking a NullReferenceException in a case like this), but passing `true` as above makes them also return private ones. Then you can examine the `IsPublic` (or `IsPrivate`) properties.

Comment: This doesn't work. See my example. Even though the get or set is private, it says that it can both read and write, as long as one of them is public.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify any binding flags you will get the public, instance properties -- which is what you want.  But then you will need to check if the PropertyType on the PropertyInfo object is of type String.  Unless you know in advance, you'll also need to check whether the property is readable/writable as @Fredrik indicates.

```
using System.Linq;

public static void ReplaceEmptyStrings<T>(List<T> list, string replacement)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                              .Where( p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) );
    foreach(var p in properties)
    {
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) p.GetValue(item, null)))
                p.SetValue(item, replacement, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance should do it

GetSetMethod()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach: [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
You can intercept the setter and set the desired value to a valid one. With [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) it's quite easy.

Comment: As I was saying, it's a different approach. Instead of changing the value *after* it is set, I suggest to intercept the setter, and change the value if needed. When using PostSharp, you can write attributes and use them with your properties.

Comment: how would you intercept a setter? wouldn't you need to have access to the class or override properties or something then?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers, but I prefer to refactor the search itself to be easly queried  with Linq, so the query could be as follow:

```
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var properties = (from prop
                              in asm.GetType()
                                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                          where 
                            prop.PropertyType == typeof (string) && 
                            prop.CanWrite && 
                            prop.CanRead
                          select prop).ToList();
        properties.ForEach(p => Debug.WriteLine(p.Name));
```

I took for my example the Assembly type, which hasn't read/write string properties, but if   the same code search for just read properties, the result will be:

- CodeBase
- EscapedCodeBase
- FullName
- Location
- ImageRuntimeVersion

Which are the **string** **read-only** Assembly type properties

Answer (score 0):

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(t);
        if (value != null /* &&  add your condition if exists */)
        {
            return /* whatever you want in your method*/;
        }
    }
}
```