# How do I get specific details about an exception from a general Exception class object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

In ASP.NET,How can i know the Specific details about an exception (like What kind of Exception it is (FileNotFound /Arithmentc etc..) )from a General Exception class object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetType()` method to get the actual type of the exception instance.

If you are interested in some property of a specific type of exception and you're sure about the type, just cast the exception to the type and fetch the property value.

Alternatively, you can [use reflection to interrogate the object and retrieve all of its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824802/c-how-to-get-all-public-both-get-and-set-string-properties-of-a-type).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the full details (stack trace, names and such) from an exception object, use the overloaded [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring%28VS.80%29.aspx) on it. It gives quite a lot of information.