# Programatically adding event handlers for all properties of <T>

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a bunch of properties of certain type  , this type has 3 events and I want to subscribe to this events on my class constructor, but avoiding typing each property name 3 times, is this possible?

Something like iterate trough all the properties of this type and add the event handlers?

```
internal class myValues {
    public myValues () {
        // Want to avoid hardcoding all my Properties here, and loop trough them all
        Test1.AnyChanged += OnMetricChanged;
        Test1.ValueChanged += OnMetricValueChanged;
        Test1.DeltaChanged += OnMetricDeltaChanged;
        ...
        ...
        // I can go trough all of them, but not sure how to add the handlers here
        var properties = typeof(myValues).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Metric));
        foreach (var p in properties) {
                Debug.WriteLine(p.Name );
        }

    }
    public Metric Test1 { get; private set; }
    public Metric Test2 { get; private set; }
    public Metric Test3 { get; private set; }
    public Metric Test4 { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: This can be solved by using reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824802/how-to-get-all-public-both-get-and-set-string-properties-of-a-type

Comment: and how do you get the handlers? Why is `AnyChanged` mapped to `OnMetricChanged` while `ValueChanged ` is mapped to `OnMetricValueChanged `? How do you map an event-handler to an event? I can't see any logic here.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Those are the handlers I want to use, they are already defined in the class (not shown there). and those are the 3 events of the type, just need to repeat that code for all my properties

Comment: but how do you know which handler to use for which event? Or do all your projects have the exact same three events and handlers?

Comment: They all use the same

Comment: @Eddi i was able to get all the properties indeed, but not sure how to add the handler once i get them
var props= typeof(myClass).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Metric))

Comment: you should add what you've tried into your question together with what problems you have with that code

Comment: FYI - the convention for naming event handlers is not to start with "On" as that is used for the method that actually raise the event in the source class.

Comment: This sounds like a solution looking for an answer.  You would maybe better looking at the mediator pattern (and MediatR nuget), which I think is a better fit for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply method extraction to property subscription and then iterate over properties via reflection to subscribe each of them

```
var myValues = new myValues();

public class Metric
{
    public event EventHandler AnyChanged;
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
    public event EventHandler DeltaChanged;
}

public class myValues
{
    public myValues()
    {
        var properties = typeof(myValues).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Metric));
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            var metric = (Metric)p.GetValue(this);
            SubscribeMetric(metric);
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Subscribed {p.Name}");
        }
    }

    private void SubscribeMetric(Metric metric)
    {
        metric.AnyChanged += OnMetricChanged;
        metric.ValueChanged += OnMetricValueChanged;
        metric.DeltaChanged += OnMetricDeltaChanged;
    }

    private void OnMetricDeltaChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnMetricValueChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnMetricChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public Metric Test1 { get; set; } = new();
    public Metric Test2 { get; set; } = new();
    public Metric Test3 { get; set; } = new();
    public Metric Test4 { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!
I didnt realize I could get the actual property as var metric = (Metric)p.GetValue(this);
Thanks a LOT

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the setter and attach my events there, instead of

```
internal class myValues {
    public Metric Test1 { get; private set; }
    public Metric Test2 { get; private set; }
    public Metric Test3 { get; private set; }
    public Metric Test4 { get; private set; }
}
```

I would do this

```
internal class myValues {
    private Metric _test1;
    private Metric _test2;
    private Metric _test3;
    private Metric _test4;

    public Metric Test1 { get => _test1; private set => SetValue(ref _test1, value); }
    public Metric Test2 { get => _test2; private set => SetValue(ref _test2, value); }
    public Metric Test3 { get => _test3; private set => SetValue(ref _test3, value); }
    public Metric Test4 { get => _test4; private set => SetValue(ref _test4, value); }

    private void SetValue(ref Metric toSet, Metric value)
    {
         //unregister events from old value
         if (toSet is not null)
         {
            toSet.AnyChanged -= OnMetricChanged;
            toSet.ValueChanged -= OnMetricValueChanged;
            toSet.DeltaChanged -= OnMetricDeltaChanged;
         }

         toSet = value;
         if (toSet is not null)
         {
            toSet.AnyChanged += OnMetricChanged;
            toSet.ValueChanged += OnMetricValueChanged;
            toSet.DeltaChanged += OnMetricDeltaChanged;
         }
    }
}
```

a different Idea would be to create the following structure instead

```
//create an "Listener" interface
interface IMetricListener
{
    //some ideas how the method could look
    void AnyChanged(Metric sender, object value);
    void ValueChanged(Metric sender, object oldValue, object newValue);
    void DeltaChanged(Metric sender);
}

class Metric
{
     private IMetricListener _listener;
     
     //pass a "Listener" object to metric
     public Metric(IMetricListener listener)
     {
          _listener = listener;
     }

     public Metric()
     {

     }

     public void Foo()
     {
         //do stuff
         
         //if _listner isnt null, call a "change" method
         _listener?.AnyChanged(this);
     }
}

//Implement IMetricListener
class myValues : IMetricListener
{
    public void AnyChanged(Metric sender, object value) => { }
    public void ValueChanged(Metric sender, object oldValue, object newValue) => { }
    public void DeltaChanged(Metric sender) => { }

    public myValues () {
        //create metrics by passing this as a listener
        Test1 = new Metric(this);
        Test2 = new Metric(this);
        Test3 = new Metric(this);
        Test4 = new Metric(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want Metric to have any setter, although I wrote a private set there, in fact they are only read only, they have a public method to set values (it as a lot of logic)

So yes, i see your logic will work but its a bit more effort that I wanted to avoid If possible

Comment: @smoke - added different idea

Comment: @Smoke - private set or not makes no difference, I simply forgot it (added it now it latest edit) - https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Uih6I

Comment: Love the idea of the interface, thanks a lot for the feedback @Rand !